# Excel VBA Use Global Connection String

Tags: vba, excel

I want use a **connection string** to a **database** but I don't now how to initialize this connection to be used in whole
Workbook:

```
cnd.Open "ODBC;DSN=Firebird;Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=" & yserver & ":" & ycale & ydb & ";CHARSET=NONE;UID=SYSDBA; PWD=blank;Client=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\fbclient.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Connections are accessible to the entire workbook by design; therefore nothing unusual needs to be done to make a connection accessible to all worksheets. If one opens the VBA Object Explorer and locates the WorkbookConnection object, it can be found at the same level in the object hierarchy as the Workbooks and Workbook objects.